# Hypersurface Normal

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, metric-tensor

Could anyone explain why

$$n^{a}n_{a}=\pm1$$

where $n^{a}$ is the normal to the [hypersurface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface)

Comment: Usually $n^a$ is the unit normal; the sign of $n^an_a$ depends on whether the normal is timelike or spacelike.

Answer (score 6):

What you said is only true if the hypersurface is space-like or time-like. If a non-null hypersurface is defined by $f(x) = $ constant, then the normal to the hypersurface is given by
$$
n_\alpha \propto \partial_\alpha f
$$
The fact that the hypersurface is non-null implies
$$
g^{\alpha\beta} \partial_\alpha f \partial_\beta f = \varepsilon\neq 0
$$
Depending on whether $\varepsilon$ is positive or negative, the hypersurface is called time-like or space-like respectively (in mostly plus signature).

We normalize $n_\alpha$ to define the unit normal vector as
$$
n_\alpha = \frac{ \partial_\alpha f}{ \sqrt{ | g^{\alpha\beta} \partial_\alpha f \partial_\beta f | }}
$$
This implies $n_\alpha n^\alpha = \pm 1$. Its just a definition.