# Definition of normal 4-vector of hypersurface in Poisson

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In Poisson book on GR (toolkit) ch-$3$ normalized normal vector on a hypersurface ($\Phi(x)=0$) is defined as $$n_{\alpha}=\frac{\epsilon\Phi_{,\alpha}}{|\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}|^{1/2}}$$ where $\epsilon$ is a constant $(\pm1)$ used to differentiate between spacelike and timelike hypersurface.

My doubt is in $(3.3)$. Here $\epsilon$ is defined as $n_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}=\epsilon$ and but according to the above definition of $n_{\alpha}$ we get $$n_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}=\frac{\epsilon^2\Phi_{,\alpha}\Phi^{,\alpha}}{\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}}$$
$$\color{red}{n_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}=\epsilon^2}$$
Due to the square on RHS we won't be able to differentiate between different spacelike and timelike hypersurface. So there has to be some mistake in the calculation. I have searched the errata but there is none for this book.

Comment: There’s also an $\epsilon$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks! It's a typo. will report it. Also, you should update it in your answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/hypersurface-normal

Comment: There is no typo. I have the book you are referring to and its eq. (3.4) and equation (and the one you have written in the question) is perfectly correct. What you need to remember is that $| \Phi^2 | = \epsilon \Phi^2$.

Comment: There is no typo in my answer either.

Comment: @Prahar yeah, I found my mistake. There is no typo anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a bit explicit for future reference. My mistake was missing the absolute sign in denominator of $n_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}$, i.e. $$n_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}=\frac{\epsilon^2\Phi_{,\alpha}\Phi^{,\alpha}}{\color{red}{|}\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}\color{red}{|}}$$ and as stated in above comments $|\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}|=\epsilon\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}$ Hence the desired result.

For spacelike hypersurface $\Phi_{,\mu}\Phi^{,\mu}<0$ my multiplying with $\epsilon=-1$ we get positive value similar calculation follows for timelike hypersurface.